# I am trying to prove the identity $ \sum_{k=m}^{n} k^{\downarrow m }{n \choose k} = n^{\downarrow m } 2^{n-m}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Prove algebraically

$\sum_{k=m}^{n} k^{\downarrow m }{n \choose k} = n^{\downarrow m } 2^{n-m}$

I have an idea as to how to prove it when m = 1, but am having trouble otherwise.

When m=1, we just have

$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{\downarrow 1 }{n \choose k} = n^{\downarrow 1 } 2^{n-1} = n2^{n-1} $

I would appreciate any insight you guys could give would be appreciated.  I do understand the identity combinatorially but am having issues with the algebra.

Longtime lurker, 1st time poster, so please forgive if I am not following proper protocol.

Comment: By $k^{\downarrow m}$ do you mean what I’d write as $k^{\underline m}=k(k-1)\dots(k-m+1)$, the falling $m$-th power?

Comment: yes, you are correct

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "prove algebraically" means? Is a counting proof not acceptable? How about a power series based proof?

Comment: Yes, a non-counting proof is required.  I am not sure about a power series based proof, but I think that would be fine.

Comment: If you've got a counting proof, there are always ways to disguise it as an algebraic proof (the converse is harder). Why should you want to forbid counting proofs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s the same basic calculation as for $m=1$, using the identity $k\binom{n}k=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ repeatedly:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=m}^{n} k^{\downarrow m }{n \choose k}&=\sum_{k=m}^n\frac{k!n!}{(k-m)!k!(n-k)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=m}^n\frac{n!}{(k-m)!(n-k)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=m}^n\frac{n^{\downarrow m}(n-m)!}{(k-m)!(n-k)!}\\
&=n^{\downarrow m}\sum_{k=m}^n\binom{n-m}{k-m}\\
&=n^{\downarrow m}\sum_{k=0}^{n-m}\binom{n-m}k\\
&=n^{\downarrow m}2^{n-m}\;.
\end{align*}$$

(But I think that the combinatorial argument gives more real insight!)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you.  And you are correct about the combinatorial argument.